# Is there a "standard" representation structure/specification for a language dictionary in JSON/XML?

Tags: json, xml

Unfortunately Googling this results in "dictionary" being interpreted as a data structure, instead of as a language dictionary.

I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
[
   {
      "english": "hello",
      "german": "hallo",
      "definitions": {
         "english": "A word of greeting"
      }
   }
]
```

I realise anyone can make something up but if there's a standard spec available that would be helpful.

Comment: If there were a standard, it would be developed by professional lexicographers who know that a dictionary is an awful lot more than a simple list of synonyms; it would be a vastly more complex standard than you are probably looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If there were a standard, it would be developed by professional lexicographers who know that a dictionary is an awful lot more than a simple list of synonyms; it would be a vastly more complex standard than you are probably looking for.

Also, you'll probably find there is more than one standard (or proposed standard) and you have to choose between them.

A quick google came up with:

DML: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00968835/document

XDXF: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XDXF

GenoPro: https://www.genopro.com/sdk/Report-Generator/Dictionary/

An IBM format: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS8NLW_11.0.2/com.ibm.discovery.es.ta.doc/iiystlexxml.html

TEI: http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/blf10/Links/TEI.html

dicML: probably dead.